# Dropdown visibility at different positioning

Tags: css

I have a drop-down list, however a problem has appeared and I cannot understand the dependency. Due to the large number of `z-index`, the menu opens out of visibility, but if I add `absolute` positioning to the menu, the menu becomes visible. However, as far as I know, the `z-index` should work with `relative` positioning. Can you explain the difference why with `absolute` positioning I see a menu, but with `relative` not.

Comment: I would add the code to view, but at the moment I can't establish the reason and I don’t know which code to add

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. Please take some time to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and/or visit [the "How to ask?" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). An important point is that In order for you to get help here, you would need to put up a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With the current info currently in your question, nobody can possibly help you.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. If you can not figure out the cause of the problem with all the html/css/javascript-code, how do you suppose we could do it without any of that? You need to narrow down the problem to a certain html-elements/css-rules etc and then add the [mcve] here.

Comment: I try to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use **position:relative**, visibility of your dropdown depends on its parent container z-index as well.
For example:

```
<header style="z-index:0;position:relative"> 
  <nav style="z-index:2;position:relative"> </nav>
</header>
<main style="z-index:1;position:relative">
</main>
```

**nav** dropdown will be covered by the  container, because "**header z-index**" < "**main z-index**".

When you apply **position:absolute**, the absolute element goes out of the normal document flow and does not depend on its parent z-index.

Comment: But if I specify the index in the descendant, it overrides the parent.

Comment: Setting z-index on an element inside block with position:relative will only change its layer with respect to other elements inside the same block.